# SVG / HTML 5 canvas - circles pattern displacement, stripe.com approach

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, html5-canvas

While browsing stripe.com website [please see this [page](https://stripe.com/us/sigma), example image bellow], one thing that caught my attention was their approach on svg pattern drawing using HTML 5 canvas.­­

I've noticed the circles pattern (orange color) are kind of displaced and doesn't seem to be tiled within its canvas as we usually see. There's a certain freedom in this pattern arrangement (not the css transform such as the skewed appearance, but the individual circles that compose the pattern itself), in a way the circles seem to be positioned randomly within the canvas but never reaches its limits.

[image]

By trying out [texture.js](https://riccardoscalco.github.io/textures/), a similar pattern model can accomplished, but despite the nice effect, it results in the common "tiled" style.

I've made an example [Pen](https://codepen.io/monecchi/pen/awOEEL). Could such effect be achieved with texture.js and additional css transformation or js function?

```
<div class="pattern">
    <div id="myCanvas" class="pattern-circles"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var w = '100%',
  h = '100%';

// The svg element
var svg = d3.select("#myCanvas")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);


// the texture
var t = textures.circles()
    //.thinner()
    .radius(4)
    .stroke("Orange")
    .fill("transparent")
    .strokeWidth(2);


svg.call(t);

// Creat the shape to add fill
svg.append("rect")
  .attr({
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "width": "1200",
    "height": "1200",
    "rx": 0,
    "ry": 0
  })
  .style({
    "fill": t.url(),
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are after, but creating a pattern like this isn't overly difficult.  Here's quick swing at it, you can adjust `radius` and `space` to adjust the "density" of the pattern:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
    
      var w = 500,
          h = 500;
      
      var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', w)
        .attr('height', h);
        
      var p = svg.append('defs')
        .append('pattern')
        .attr('id', 'chaos')
        .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
        .attr('width', w)
        .attr('height', h);
        
      var space = 20,
          radius = 5,
          col = 1,
          row = 1;
          
      for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        
        var cx = (col * space) + (Math.random() * radius + space),
            cy = (row * space) + (Math.random() * radius + space);
            
        col += 1;
        
        if (cy > (h - space)) {
          break;
        }
        
        if (cx > (w - space)) {
          
          col = 1;
          row += 1
          
        } else {
          
          p.append('circle')
            .style('stroke', 'orange')
            .style('fill', 'none')
            .attr('r', radius)
            .attr('cx', cx)
            .attr('cy', cy);
        }
      }
        
      svg.append('rect')
        .attr('width', w)
        .attr('height', h)
        .style('fill', 'url(#chaos)')
        .style('stroke', 'steelblue');

      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```